# My Server does not run PHP files. Giving me error

Tags: php, apache, webserver

Hello recently i have taken a backup of my server files & deleted all my files from server....

Now when i am uploading my files again on server, HTML files do work but PHP files do not work.

The file i am using is index.php, when i upload this file the following error gets generated:-

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to
complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mindsoftindia.com and inform them of
the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Before, I had these folders on my server along with my website files:-

1. cgi-bin
2. cp
3. modlogan

Also, i again uploaded these folders again but still PHP files do not work.

Comment: I think the important part of that message is `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`, you should check there for details on what's wrong.

Comment: Check the Apache `error_log` to see why it might be failing, sometimes you can find it somewhere in `/etc` or `/usr/local` or `/var` under httpd or apache(2).

Comment: The error you're getting is very generic. It could be that PHP is working fine, and there's just an error in that specific file. Could you post the PHP code from index.php here? 

If you're able to look at your server's error log, you could also check there to see if there's a more specific message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i asked my server administrator, He re-installed everything.... Thanks for all your time and effort....

Answer (score 1):

try to run the phpinfo file to check if php is properly confirgured in your localhost

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-test-php-installation-with-a-phpinfo-page/

Answer (score 0):

If seen this error over and over and was always referring to non-supported configs on `.htaccess` files.

Do check them.